# How to nest 2 rows inside of <td> in DataTables table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

Here's a structure that I want to archive coupled with DataTables plugin.

[image]

As you can see the address it taking 3 columns.

The following html **break** datatables sorting functionality. And the table looks shifted.

Here's an example with different data but the idea is the same.

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tr>
           <td >Some very long lorem ipsum text</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Angelica Raaaaamos</td>   
           <td>Accountant</td>
           <td>Tokyo</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
  </td>

  <td>33</td>
  <td>2008/11/28</td>
  <td>$162,700</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

**upd**

> **The grey text is not a group. Every item in a table(every row) should**
>   **have it included**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [RowGroup](https://datatables.net/download/release#RowGroup) extension which will let you group rows by given data point.

> [**RowGroup**](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/)
>
> *The ability to group rows in a table can let an end user quickly and easily see the structure of the data shown, and also present them with summaries of the data shown in each group. RowGroup adds this ability to DataTables with the ability to customise the start and end grouping rows displayed in the DataTable, letting you integrate the summarised data to fit perfectly in with your site.*

Using the `rowGroup` option as an object, will give you the ability to use a couple of options to define the look and source data for the row-group. For all the available options take a look [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/#rowgroup).

Here is an example, sure you'll get the idea. ;)

```js
var dataSet = [
  [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800", "Foo foo foo foo bla bla" ],
  [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750", "Some very long lorem ipsum text" ],
  [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000", "Bar bar bar bar bla bla" ],
]

$('#example').DataTable({

  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { title: "Name" },
    { title: "Position" },
    { title: "Office" },
    { title: "Extn." },
    { title: "Start date" },
    { title: "Salary" },
  ],
  rowGroup: {
    startRender: function(row, group) {
      if(typeof group == "string") {
        return $('<tr/>')
          .append('<td colspan="6"><span>' + group + '</span></td>');
      }
    },
    endRender: null,
    className: 'table-group',
    dataSrc: 6
  }

});
```

```css
table.dataTable tbody th, table.dataTable tbody .table-group td {
    padding: 0;
}

table.dataTable tbody th, table.dataTable tbody .table-group td span {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    display: block;
    color: silver;
}

table.dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(4n),
table.dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(4n-1) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.0/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.0/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not exactly what I'm looking for. On the first screenshot the grey text is not a group. It's just a text that should be different in every row item. I was thinking about using col/row spans but it looks like DataTables plugin doesn't support it...

Comment: Not sure if i understand you correctly, but using the `rowGroup` you can add individual text on each row, just add it to your data source, simple as that. I made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You can get an idea from here:**
try to hide your `td` as `<td style='display:none;'></td>`

```js
$( function(){
 $('#id-table').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table id='id-table' border='1'>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Angelica Raaaaamos</th>   
    <th>Accountant</th>
    <th>Tokyo</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">Some very long lorem ipsum text</td>
   <td style='display:none;'></td>
   <td style='display:none;'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Angelica Raaaaamos</td>   
    <td>Accountant</td>
    <td>Tokyo</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This result **(Reversed Row)** you get is bcoz, DataTable is sorted on **First Column**
You can **CHANGE** it.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

use two extra blank td there.
like:

```
 <tr>
   <td >Some very long lorem ipsum text</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
```

if it doesn't work, then use width in styling. like:

```
   <tr >
       <td style="width:50px">Some very long lorem ipsum text</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
      <tr >
       <td style="width:50px">Some</td>
       <td>Acountant</td>
       <td>london</td>
     </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have simply put this in a comment, but since my reputation is too low i'll suggest you to take a look at [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)

In the drawCallback you have to append your `<td>` before the row you want it to be in.

I could be more specific if I had your jQuery Code